# separate street number from street name in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I having trouble to extract number of street. Here some examples:

```
var1 <- c("roma street 4 - 6", "venezia street 7A", "venezia 5, square 3")
```

I need to extract only the numbers of street and so, I only want to have:

```
"4 - 6","7A","5, 3"
```

I am trying using:

```
gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", var1)
```

but it give back only numbers

Comment: What is the rule here? Try [`gsub("(,\\s*)?.*?(\\d\\w*(?:[\\d\\s-]*\\d\\w*)?)", "\\1\\2", var1)`](https://regex101.com/r/YQ4gaU/1), it is all I could do with your current data.

Comment: Perhaps : gsub("[[:lower:]]", "", var1)

Comment: the use of lower is genial! but in case of: "Via Maggio 1C" it give me back V M 1 C.

Comment: also wiktor solution is very good and it help me to find new problematic cases, for exampe: "18, Avenue Louis" give back "18 Avenue Lous" and "Kalenderplaz 101, Glattpark" give back  "Kalenderplaz 101, Glattpark". And "Via Maghetti" give back ""Via Maghetti"

Comment: or something like `sub('^.*?(?=\\d)', '', perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @useR - No, [that doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/CVmVyt/1)

Comment: Try [`regmatches(var1, gregexpr("\\d\\w*(?:[\\d\\s-]*\\d\\w*)?", var1))`](https://ideone.com/hlIOnA)

Comment: really impressive Wiktor! Just last problem:

Comment: Just last problem Wiktor: consider this: "Via Maggio 1 C" give back "1" and not "1C" or "1 C". I am trying to chenage yuor solution above but it's not esy to find the solution.